# SMTP Mail Service is not working in AEM 6.4 (Service pack 7) - Invalid mail service configuration

Tags: email, smtp, aem

We are trying to send email from an AEM Service using *MessageGatewayService* API. The weird part is, it is working on all lower environment and including in our local aem instance but it is not working only in Live servers. We verified the below things

- Verified org.apache.sling.healthcheck: smtpMailService service
  (*/system/console/jmx/org.apache.sling.healthcheck%3Aname%3DsmtpMailService%2Ctype%3DHealthCheck*),
  it says “**The E-mail Service appears to be working properly. Verify
  the health check e-mail was sent to [ healthcheck@example.com ]**”
- Verified that the smtp host is open with port number using telnet from both author and publish servers
- Restarted Day Communique 5 Mailer com.day.cq.cq-mailer bundle

Error Message:-

```
com.day.cq.mailer.MailingException: Invalid mail service configuration.

        at com.day.cq.mailer.impl.DefaultMailService.send(DefaultMailService.java:270)

        at com.day.cq.mailer.impl.DefaultMailService.send(DefaultMailService.java:45)
```

Is there any additional configuration to verify?

Answer (score 2):

This problem got resolved after restarting AEM servers